# Using a format string passed in by the user to output variables into with Python

Tags: python, file, csv, pandas

Hopefully the title makes sense as I don't really know how to phrase this well.

I'm using Python and am writing something to parse through iTunes weirdly formatted text files that are made when you export playlist data. I used panda to read a csv, and can loop through each column that iTunes made. For reference here is an example on how this file is laid out:

```
Name     Artist         Album
Song 1   Hello World    Hey how are [you]
Text     Me Back        Please!
Hey      Python         Is Coo-l
```

I read them in with:

```
import pandas as pd
colnames = [ 'Name', 'Artist', 'Album' ]
data = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', delim_whitespace = False, header = None, names = colnames)

format_string = '[Name] -> [Album] ::: "[Artist]"'
```

The `format_string` is how I want to print them out to a file. I want to be able to scan a string and replace the column name in between `[column_name]` with the value in the current row while looping through every row. I also want the user to specify this string, so if the `column_name` matches with a column in `colnames`, then we proceed with converting it to that format.

For the example above, this code would use the `format_string` to loop through and come out with this text file:

```
Song 1 -> Hey how are [you] ::: "Hello World"
Text -> Please! ::: "Me Back"
Hey -> Is Coo-l ::: "Python"
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this in Python 3.x. [This](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) or other tutorial about format string will help you.

```
print('{0} -> {1} ::: "{2}"'.format(name, album, artist))
```

Also, as for your case (`pandas`), print like this.

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    print('{0} -> {1} ::: "{2}"'.format(data['Name'][i], data['Album'][i], data['Artist'][i]))
```